# Convert Pandas Dataframe Column To R Factors

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

I am trying to convert a column of a pandas dataframe to factor because the function I am trying to call in R expects factors.

```
pandas2ri.activate()    
#second column of labels has to be converted to factors
labels = read_csv(path_to_csv)
as_factor = ro.r['as.factor']
output = package.function(another_df, as_factor(labels['column_name']))
```

Following is the error I get:

```
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

What should I do?

Reproducible example below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': [10, 20],
                   'x': ['Control', 'Low_Cav02']})

from rpy2 import robjects as ro

from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

as_factor = ro.r['as.factor']

labels = as_factor(df['Col'])
print labels

labels = as_factor(df['x'])
print labels
```

Output:

```
[1] 10 20
Levels: 10 20

/Users/swetabh/Envs/damet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py:106: UserWarning: Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?

  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "damet/analysis.py", line 26, in <module>
    labels = as_factor(df['x'])
  File "/Users/swetabh/Envs/damet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 178, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/swetabh/Envs/damet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 106, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Comment: could you try to show a reproducible example that we can run as well to help you?

Comment: I don't know if it would solve your issue but R's factor's equivalent is category in pandas: `df["some_column"].astype("category")`

Comment: @MathieuB Done. Lmk if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is working just fine on my end. Which version of `rpy2` are you using ?

**Edit:** orginal answer below - I misunderstood the question

If trying to create an R `DataFrame`, the default converter in rpy2 turn Python lists into R lists.
If you want an R vector use the constructors for vectors.

With your example this could look like:

```
df = ro.DataFrame({'Col': ro.vectors.IntVector([10, 20]),
                   'x': ro.vectors.StrVector(['Control', 'Low_Cav02'])})
```

Comment: I get the following error when I do this: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: Yes. I somehow managed to both misread the question and write non-working code in the answer. I am editing the answer now.